# Picasso Library: Does Fit() function resize the image?

Tags: android, image, resize, picasso

I am currently using the Picasso to load the image file to image view on android. I tried to have an image resized then using fit to fit on the imageView. The fit cannot be used with resize.

```
Picasso.With().Load().Resize().Fit().Into()
```

Does the fit function will resize the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Document](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fit--) of Picasso

> Attempt to resize the image to fit exactly into the target ImageView's
>   bounds. This will result in delayed execution of the request until the
>   ImageView has been laid out.

So i think the fit function will resize the image.